# Will switching my default encoding (Java, Spring) to UTF32 slow down my software?

Tags: encoding

This is the main thing about UTF32 that I was concerned about. I haven't really noticed anything due to the size of my software.
But I imagine after 100000 rows or 10000 searches, memory use would be way up at least.

As someone who wants to become a professional, should I universally as possible OR by default, switch to using UTF32?

Comment: It will slow down your data transfers, for a start.

Comment: You should use whatever is commonly used or, barring that, whatever is convenient for your environment. For unicode, that's usually utf-8 or utf-16. As for speed, utf-32 will of course require more memory and so slow down anything that would be slowed down by having to deal with more data (though that decrease may not be particularly significant). This would include any task that has to examine, compare, or transfer that data.